# Add-in function Range.Delete method fails

Tags: vba, excel, range, excel-addins

First, I would like to apologize for my bad language, I hope you'll understand my problem.

I looked after a way to get generic function in Excel and I found the add-in method. So I tried to use it in developping custom functions whitch may help me in my everyday work. I developed a first function which work. So I thought that my add-in programmation and installation was good. But when I try to implement worksheet interractions nothing appened.

My code has to delete rows identified by a special code in a cell of those ones. I get no error message and the code seems to be totally executed. I tried other methods like Cells.delete, Cells.select, worksheet.activate or range.delete but I encounter the same issue.

This is my function's code :

```
Public Function NotBin1Cleaning(rSCell As Range) As Integer
Dim sht                 As Worksheet
Dim aLine               As New ArrayList
Dim iLine               As Integer
Dim iCpt                As Integer
Dim iFail               As Integer
Dim i                   As Integer
Dim oRange              As Object

Set sht = rSCell.Parent
iLine = sht.Cells.Find("*PID*").Row
For Each rCell In Range(sht.Cells(iLine, 1), sht.Cells(sht.Cells(iLine, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 1))
    If sht.Cells(rCell.Row, 2) > 1 Then
        iLine = rCell.Row
        iCpt = iLine + 1
        Do Until sht.Cells(iCpt, 2) = 1
            If Not sht.Cells(iCpt, 1) = rCell Then Exit Do
            iCpt = iCpt + 1
        Loop
        If sht.Cells(iCpt, 1) = rCell Then
            sht.Range(sht.Cells(iLine, 1), sht.Cells(iCpt - 1, sht.Cells(iCpt, 1).End(xlToRight).Column)).Delete xlUp
            iFail = iFail + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
NotBin1Cleaning = iFail
End Function
```

it's the line:

```
sht.Range(sht.Cells(iLine, 1), sht.Cells(iCpt - 1, sht.Cells(iCpt, 1).End(xlToRight).Column)).Delete xlUp
```

which isn't producing any effect.

I would be really thankful for your help.

Comment: Have you verified that `sht` is definitely referring to the Worksheet that it should be?

Comment: Yes, when I guess sht.name, it gives me back the good sheet name.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the function `NotBin1Cleaning` is in an add-in. You are then calling `NotBin1Cleaning` inside an Excel Cell? Such as `=NotBin1Cleaning(A1)`?

Comment: yes I am, and the code is executed correctly but nothing appen on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is described on the Microsoft support site as part of the intentional design**

*section below, [more detail here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel) (emphasis mine)*

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such
>   a function ***cannot*** do any of the following:
>
> - ***Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.***
> - Change another cell's value.
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook.
> - Set properties or execute most methods.
>
> The purpose of user-defined functions is to allow the user to create a
>   custom function that is not included in the functions that ship with
>   Microsoft Excel. The functions included in Microsoft Excel also cannot
>   change the environment. Functions can perform a calculation that
>   returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in.
>   Any environmental changes should be made through the use of a Visual
>   Basic subroutine.

Essentially, this means that what you're trying to do won't work in such a concise manner. The limitation, as I understand from further reading, is because Excel runs through cell equation/functions several times to determine dependencies. This would lead to your function being called two or more times. If you could delete rows, there is the potential of accidentally deleting more then twice the numbers of rows intended, due to the excess number of runs.

However, an alternative could be to have the function output a unique string result that shouldn't be found anywhere else in your workbook (maybe something like `[@]><`).

Then you can have a sub, ran *manually*, which finds all instances of that unique string, and deletes those rows. (*Note:* if you included any of the typical wildcard symbols in your string, you will have to precede them with a `~` to find them with the `.Find` method.) You can even set up the sub/macro with a shortcut key. **Caution:** if you duplicate a shortcut key Excel already uses, it will run the macro instead of the default. If there will be other users using this workbook, they could experience some unexpected results.

If you decide to go this route, I would recommend using this line:

```
Public Const dummy_str = "[@]><" ' whatever string you decided on.
```

in your module with your code. It goes outside any functions or subs, so it'll be global, and then you can refer to the const just as you would any other string variable.

Answer (score -3):

When you write:

```
sht.Range(sht.Cells(iLine, 1),....
```

This first parameter should be the row number, but you're refering to a Cell instead. You should change `sht.Cells(iLine, 1)` for `iLine`.

BUT

Instead of all this, its easier to use the method `Row.Delete`:

```
Rows(iLine).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: According to the code attached to the question, `Dim iLine As Integer`, `iLine` would not be a range. Looking at one of the variable assignments, `iLine = rCell.Row`, `iLine` is being assigned the **row number** of a range. However, I do agree that the `Rows(iLine).EntireRow.Delete` may be easier.

Comment: I tried this method to, but it doesn't work at all. When I perfofmed the fonction in a macro worbook standard (xlsm), all commands work. It'd when I use the .xla format where I enconter the problem.